# How can I beat Grand Widow Faerlina on heroic?

Tags: hearthstone

Her 1 mana spam is just ridiculous.  I beat her on normal using a zoolock deck but the weenie minions get eaten up way too fast.  Her worshippers giving her a 3 damage attack doesn't help things either.  What are some strategies to use against her?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I beat her with a normal zoolock deck on my first try. Just drop your hand as fast as possible, never keep more than one card at the end of your turn if you can help it and try to kill her board every turn. Only Life Tap when you are out of cards.

In any case be sure to have 2 Shieldbearers, 2 Voiswalkers, and 2 Defender of Argus, to stop her from killing your more important minions with her face.

Also she seems very reluctant to use her hero power if you have a Nerubian Egg on the board.

The list I used is this one: http://www.hearthpwn.com/decks/76029-reynads-naxx-zoo-deck replacing the Elven Archers with Shieldbearers.

Comment: how does your deck have a legendary of a wing that's not released yet?

Comment: @z' Sorry, I linked the wrong deck, corrected.

Comment: ok, that worked much better.  Managed to dump my entire hand by turn 3 and that nullified her abilities.

Comment: Speaking of Warlock, mulliganing super-aggressively for Soulfires and Succubi and playing them within the first turns can effectively turn her ability off by turn 2. I've found this to be a very effective strategy as it basically reduces her to a 45 life Warrior with those pesky Fanatics. For these, 4 attack are crucial. Shadow Bolt, Yeti, Darkscale Healer and Windfury Harpie can all kill them efficiently, although the latter are risky because of their high cost.

Comment: I used zoolock as well - works like charm. This is imho the easiest heroic challenge.

Answer (score 0):

I was eventually able to beat Faerlina with a priest deck that spammed Silence. Against Faerlina, your strategy needs to be two-fold:

1. Play cards to mitigate the effectiveness of Rain of Fire
2. Maintain control of the board

Number 1 is not quite as simple as it might seem -- if you have too many cards in your hand, minions you play will simply be perforated by Rain of Fire before they can do much of anything. Against this, you really need tough, HP heavy minions, since the damage soak they provide is essential to surviving to the midgame.

Shieldbearer's 0/4 taunt is surprisingly effective at this, as is (since I was playing priest) cards like Power Word: Shield. Lightwell helps too, both with its bulk and its heal (and Faerlina will often ignore it)

The second part is a little bit harder. The minion you need to watch out for are the fanatics that increase Faerlina's attack directly. Since they give Faerlina 3 attack *immediately*, its as if they come into play with a 3/-- charge minion. And the Grand Widow has **at least three** of them. Again, as Priest, this is where I prioritized my silences. A 2/4 is easy to handle behind a strong taunt minion, but the effective 5/4 when they're powering up the Grand Widow is no joke. Consider also silencing the nerubian eggs, as even if you ignore it, Faerlina is willing to throw inner rages at it to pop it herself.

Beyond that, strong taunts, like Sen'jin and Sunwalker are the way to go. If you can keep her board clear while keeping your hand size down, you'll be in a very good position to survive her onslaught and beat her. Good luck!